# Does optimizing parameters of a function f(x) and of the log(f(x)) yelds the same result?

Tags: logarithm, optimization

When optimizing the cost function below for the BD/NBD model, I saw that the implementation in python ( [lifetimes](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifetimes/blob/master/lifetimes/fitters/beta_geo_fitter.py) ) takes the logs of all the terms of the equation in order to avoid underflow (since we are multiplying very small numbers). [image]
We can then separate this expression in A1, A2, A3 and A4, like that:
[image]
So the questions are:

1) when optimizing parameters of a model (in this case, maximizing the four attributes r, alpha, a and b), why taking the log does not change the whole thing? I mean, is maximizing f(x) the same as maximizing log(f(x)), generating thus the same values for r, alpha, a and b? What is the mathematical reasoning behind it?

2) In the algorithm, when returning the result, the second part of the expression is replaced by the logsumexp (below),

[image]

instead of using the regular math transformations, like this

[image]

Why is this valid?

Comment: If $f(x)>0$ everywhere, then note that if $f(x)>f(y)$, $\log(f(x))>\log(f(y))$, so the $x$-value that maximizes $f$ is also the $x$ value that maximizes $\log(f(x))$. The same argument applies to any monotonic increasing transform $t()$ applied to $f$.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be covered by the answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87409/example-how-maximizing-and-minimizing-a-function-can-be-equivalent/87423#87423